# Armor stand holding a written book

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I need help. So I need a armor stand to summon with a written book. I use this command to summon him.

EDIT: The written book should have text in it. So I need him to hold a custom made book. :D

```
/summon armor_stand X Y Z {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1b,Rotation:[87f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:"ITEM",Count:1b},{}],Pose:{RightArm:[180f,0f,90f]}}
```

Comment: So you've tried basically nothing before asking? This is not a "we program your stuff for free" site, we're here to solve problems you face when trying on your own.

Comment: WOWOOWOO. Take a chill pill bro. I did not have any idea on how to do it. I tried to give him just a written book but it did not work. If I don't know how to do it in anyway possible and I have tried my best and I'm still learning command blocks, then I should not ask?

Comment: Well, what DID you try? What did you research? Have you tried `/give`-ing the book to you first so that you have a working version of that command? Have you looked at the wiki?

Comment: Dude... EVERY time I say that I have tried to search but with no luck, you say it doesn't help. So I stoped saying that.

Comment: Tell us what results you got and why they didn't help. Otherwise people will just direct you to the same pages again.

Comment: Just saying you searched doesn't really help us help you.  Show us what you found.  Tell us why it doesn't work.  Showing effort goes an incredibly long way here at Arqade.  With your low quality current contributions, you're in danger of being blocked from being to ask any more questions here.  Put in some effort, show us what you've tried, and we might be able to keep helping you.  Don't, and, well, the system will ensure you can't ask anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the item in your command which is `written_book`.  You also need to specify the dataTag value of the item which includes the tags that make up the book. [Here is the wiki on the data values](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Written_Book#Data_values) of written books.  In your case, probably just `title`, `author`, and `pages`.

Here is your armor stand holding a sample book:

```
/summon armor_stand <x> <y> <z> {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,NoBasePlate:1b,NoGravity:1b,ShowArms:1b,Rotation:[87f],ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{}],HandItems:[{id:"minecraft:written_book",Count:1b,tag:{pages:["{\"text\":\"Sample book page 1\"}","{\"text\":\"Sample book page 2\"}"],title:"Sample Book",author:IronAnvil}},{}],Pose:{RightArm:[180f,0f,90f]}}
```

Comment: Hmm gonna check it out :D.

Comment: If the written book you want is fairly complicated, I recommend using a [written book give generator](http://minecraft.tools/en/book.php).  You can then copy and paste the dataTag portion from the give command into your armor stand command in the tag section.